# Auto-increment column based on value of other column

Tags: oracle12c

Looking for the best, simplest way to populate a revision level column in a Oracle 12c database table.

Example, when DESIGN1 is created, a row is inserted into table DESIGN_REVISIONS.

```
  DESIGN_NUM  REVISION  COMMENT
> DESIGN1     0         New Design
```

If a change is made to DESIGN1, then another row is inserted into the DESIGN_REVISIONS table.

```
  DESIGN_NUM  REVISION  COMMENT
  DESIGN1     0         New Design
> DESIGN1     1         Widget width increased
```

DESIGN2, DESIGN3, etc. will also start at revision 0.

Is there a way to define a primary key on DESIGN_NUM and REVISION and make REVISION an auto-increment or identity column that will automatically go to the next value for a given DESIGN_NUM, or do I have to use a sub-query in my insert query to count the existing revisions to calculate the next revision number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below steps:
Create table with Default revision value 0

```
 create table test2
 (
   d_num varchar2(100),
   revision number DEFAULT 0
 );
```

Create Row level Trigger on table as shown below. As and when the row is inserted, revision value will be calculated and inserted into table by trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER test2_rev
before INSERT ON test2
REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
declare
cnt number;

BEGIN
  cnt:=0;
  select count(*) into cnt from test2 where d_num=: NEW.d_num;

  if (cnt >0) then

   SELECT max(revision)+1
   INTO   :NEW.revision
   FROM   test2 
   where d_num=: NEW.d_num group by d_num  ;

  end if;
END;
```

Comment: I have implemented this and it's working.  One question though: what is the significance of the REFERENCING keyword (and what would happen if it were left out)?